# Can't assign shortcut key to VSIX dynamic menu comand

Tags: c#, menuitem, vsix

I need to assign a shortcut key to a dynamic menu item in a VS 2015 extension. The vsct file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>
    <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>

    <Commands package="guidPackage">

        <Groups>
            <Group guid="guidMenu" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
                <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
            </Group>
            <Group guid="guidSubMenu" id="MyMenuSubgroup" priority="0x0100">
                <Parent guid="guidMenu" id="SubMenu"/>
            </Group>
        </Groups>

        <Menus>
            <Menu guid="guidMenu" id="SubMenu" priority="0x0100" type="Menu">
                <Parent guid="guidMenu" id="MyMenuGroup"/>
                <Strings>
                    <ButtonText>Minimal commands</ButtonText>
                    <CommandName>MinimalCommands</CommandName>
                </Strings>
            </Menu>
        </Menus>

        <Buttons>
            <Button guid="guidSubMenu" id="idTest" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
                <Parent guid="guidSubMenu" id="MyMenuSubgroup" />
                <CommandFlag>DynamicItemStart</CommandFlag>
                <Strings>
                    <ButtonText>Invoke Minimal Test</ButtonText>
                    <CommandName>MinimalTest</CommandName>
                </Strings>
            </Button>
        </Buttons>

    </Commands>

    <Symbols>
        <GuidSymbol name="guidPackage" value="{3e88287b-7b79-403d-ae8d-3329af218869}" />
        <GuidSymbol name="guidMenu" value="{c1388361-6429-452c-8ba0-580d292ef0ca}">
            <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x1020" />
            <IDSymbol name="SubMenu" value="0x200"/>
        </GuidSymbol>
        <GuidSymbol name="guidSubMenu" value="{09E1B0D1-E466-4263-9D00-2EDCBDD954B2}">
            <IDSymbol name="idTest" value="0x0100" />
            <IDSymbol name="MyMenuSubgroup" value="0x1021"/>
        </GuidSymbol>
    </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

I have code that adds "Dynamic Command 1" and "Dynamic Command 2" in place of the "Minimal Test" command you see in the .vsct file. The menu displays correctly:

> Tools
>
> > Minimal Commands >
> >
> > > Dynamic Command 1
> > >       Dynamic Command 2

Clicking on the menu invokes the handler. So far so good.

Now for the problem: I can't see the two dynamic commands in the Tools.Options.Keyboard list. Based on the unanswered question at [Can one assign keyboard shortcuts to Visual Studio 2012 extensibility package commands that use DynamicItemStart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487894/can-one-assign-keyboard-shortcuts-to-visual-studio-2012-extensibility-package-co), it appears that the problem derives from having menu items that overlay a DynamicItemStart. My example is more complicated because it uses a different GUID for the dynamic command submenu. [My real app has a command filter derived from IOleCommandTarget. It hangs just before QueryStatus if the DynamicItemStart item is in the same GUID group as the fixed commands.] But I don't think the multiple GUIDs are contributing to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following the lead of the cited post, I defined a few placeholder buttons, none of which has the DynamicItemStart attribute but each of which does have the DefaultInvisible, DynamicVisibility, and TextChanges attributes. In my QueryStatus handler, I use an OLETEXTCMD class (found on this site) to change the name from Placeholderxxx to something more useful. The menu displays as I was hoping it would. The only glitch, also noticed in the cited post, is that the keyboard shortcut list uses the Placeholderxxx names. Because of this imperfection, I don't plan to release my extension (a macro processor that I need to make VS 2015 useful) to the wild.

I sure do wish there were a better solution to the problem of defining dynamic menu items.